# May one hang Torah passages or ketubah in the marital bedroom?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, marriage, tznius-modesty, ketubah

I understand that one is not supposed to store holy books in one's marital bedroom, unless they are covered. I gather that this is due to the fact that marital relations occur there, and there is a rule that one should not be naked in the presence of holy books. On the same logic, is there anything wrong with displaying (in a frame on the wall) something with Torah passages on it, or something like a Ketubah, in one's marital bedroom?

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong with a Ketuba. It's not Torah. (I also don't know why you want to hang it anywhere the husband can access.)

Comment: @DoubleAA the kesuvah is supposed to be put away and not hung up for the reason that you suggest (so that the husband does not access it). Many people have a fancy or artistic **copy** hanging up. However, the original is kept like the deed to a house or a will.

Comment: @sabbahillel No. She can do whatever she wants with it. It might be _risky_ to put it where the husband can access it (including wherever they keep the deed to the house which I assume he can access too) but that is her prerogative. There is no "supposed to".

Comment: @DoubleAA Why can't the husband have access to it?

Comment: @Yehoshua He can have access. It's just a stupid thing for the wife to do, because he could steal the document and bring it to court and claim he paid her the money and this is his receipt.

Comment: @Yehoshua The document is also "supposed" to give the specifics of how much we will owe her and if he made any additional promises to her, if the kethubbah gets lost, then there is no proof of his obligations to her. Nowadays Ashkenazim and most Sephardim have a standard fill in the blank kethubbah which limits or standardizes his obligations toward her. However there are still people (and communities like the Yemenites) that draft their own kethubbah with their own specific obligations. i chose to draft my own as the standardized sephardic one didn't protect my wife enough.